# BOX-COX TRANSFORMATION always stabilize variance

Tags: arima, data-transformation, normalization, variance-stabilizing

I am aware that box-cox transformation may make data set significantly normal distributed with constant mean and variance. But sometimes fails to convert data into normal. My question is even though box-cox transformation can not make data significantly normal, it is always make variance and mean constant?

Comment: None of the methods work in *all* situations and under *all* circumstances, and I would not expect Box-Cox transformation to be an exception to the rule.

Comment: You are right but only method on Google is box cox. Whenever I search for variance stabilization box cox always pop up. That is why I consult you. Could tell me what are the other possible methods to make variance stabilize?

Comment: It does not necessarily make variance constant (see: [Alternatives to one-way ANOVA for heteroskedastic data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/91872/7290)).

Comment: Not necessarily, but many boxcox algos actually use a 3-parameter normal distribution so that, even for data that are heteroscedastic across a range of predictors, you can estimate a simple exponential rule (including log) that gives you a change of variable that is somewhat heteroscedastic.

Comment: which is precisely why I said "may" in my answer /comments. .

Comment: Internet searching “variance stabilization” probably won’t do a good job of suggesting alternatives. This is the word for using the delta method in a clever way, which is what Box Cox is based on. Box Cox is like the delta method but it automatically chooses the power for you by making it a parameter of the model.

Answer (score 2):

1) You say "I am aware that box-cox transformation MAY make data set significantly normal distributed with constant mean and variance."

No  it simply decouples a possible relationship between the variance of the errors and the Expected value. Please read my answer to [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers). It MAY generate a more normal distribution if the series is leptokurtric (fat tails)

2) You say/ask  "does it is always make variance and mean constant?"

Not necessarily as the error variance may change deterministically over time requiring Generalized Least Squares (Weighted least Squares see http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html ) or stochastically over time requiring a GARCH add-on.

The reason Box-Cox shows up is that in the "old bad days ! " that is all that was known or in textbooks as a way to treat heteroscedastic errors. Textbooks are out of date as soon as they get printed. SE is the true textbook because it is ever evolving to improve the craft .

Also see a number of my posts where the error variance changes and in particular [Removing Variance in Time Series After Applying Log Transformation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384905/removing-variance-in-time-series-after-applying-log-transformation/384907#384907) might be of interest and [Box Cox Transformation makes Out of sample Forecast Error worse?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190436/box-cox-transformation-makes-out-of-sample-forecast-error-worse) .

Finally an examination of why intervention detection may be more useful that a box-cox transformation. http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/vegas_ibf_09a.pdf (slide 14 + )

EDITED after remarks

[image]

Comment: Those must have been awfully old textbooks, because weighted least squares has been around for a couple of centuries :-).

Comment: but it took TSAY to suggest it as treatment for arima errors and even then didn't label it as Weighted Least Squares

Comment: Where does the question have anything at all to do with ARIMA errors?  Quite clearly it's far more general than that.

Comment: agreed ... all I was politely saying was that his treatment of non-constant variance for a set of residuals was to bootstrap the weights based upon evidented variance changes . This  significant contribution is what motivated me  as a developer/publisher to broadcast it's important value