# Example use of ARMA forecasting method 

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have no experience in forecasting, so can anyone give me a step-by-step example or link to example-real values with ARMA forecasting method application?

Comment: What do you want to forecast? What textbook treatments have you looked at so far? What level of a treatment are you looking for? If you want theoretical, Brockwell & Davis is a good text. At a slightly lower level are the texts by Hamilton and by Box, Jenkens, and Reinsel. For a little more applied focus, see R. Tsay's financial time-series text. All or none of those may be what you're looking for, so it would help to expand your question to include more detail.

Comment: You might want to see my response to : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/seeking-certain-type-of-arima-explanation/9017#9017

Comment: I need a forecast of rail transport demand, but with fuzzy inputs. So, my, end aim is to make a fuzze forecast using FARMA, but since I have no experience in forecasting, I think that I have to learn something about ARMA and the pass to fuzzy case. As you know I am very new in this (exponential smoothing and simpler methods were the all my knowledge in forecasting), but after a few days of reading "Introduction to Time Series Analysis and Forecasting" by Montomery, I think that this will be my favourite subject in the future.

Comment: The problem is, that I have a very little time for now, and I need a literature in which I have a step by step real example for ARMA, even better FARMA.

Comment: @cardinal Your comment above looks like an answer to the question and actually a pretty good one.  So why did you leave it as a comment?

Answer (score 2):

In [R](http://cran.r-project.org/), you can look at the help documents for [arima](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=stats:arima) and [auto.arima](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=forecast:auto.arima) (from the [forecast package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html)) for some short examples of arima modeling.

For example:

```
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
plot(forecast(fit,h=20))
```

[image: auto.arima model]