# Example of auto-regressive integrated moving average (ARIMA) model

Tags: arima

I need simple example of ARIMA model, that performs forecasting on a small time series set e.g., (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4), (x5,y5), (x6,y6)

I found many definitions from various places… but I couldn't find a solved example.

Comment: How the coefficients of AR model are computed?

Comment: A useful page is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/seeking-certain-type-of-arima-explanation

Comment: See http://otexts.com/fpp/8/8/