# Evaluating results of VAR (Vector Autoregression) using R

Tags: r, vector-autoregression, prediction, causality

I am trying to evaluate the results of a prediction obtained with the R function **VAR**. I have reproduced an example with two time series so that others can also implement it (the data set is read from a url). After seeing the code, I have a question regarding how to plot the prediction and I would appreciate if someone helps me understand how the predict function works as well.

1) In my case, the granger test is passed for "views granger cause unemployment." When I use predict, are the values of the "views" used in the prediction of the unemployment (in this case 5 months)? How can I make a plot where the predicted values are plotted and the real values are plotted as well? On top of that, how can  I plot the results of VAR (with the real values and predicted values) and compare them with the results of only AR for unemployment (with predicted and real values as well)?. In the prediction of the VAR for unemployment, are the values of "views" considered in the 5 predicted months?

Thanks.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(vars)
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)
library(fUnitRoots)
library(urca)
library(vars)
library(aod)
library(zoo)
library(tseries)


paired.ds <- read.table(url("http://ruthygarcia.com/others/test.txt"), header=T, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

### Check for  heteroscedasticity based on http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/when-to-log-transform-a-time-series-before-fitting-an-arima-model
if ( gqtest(paired.ds$unemployment ~1)$p.value < 0.1) {

  paired.ds$unemployment <- log(paired.ds$unemployment)
}

if ( gqtest(paired.ds$views ~1)$p.value < 0.1) {

  paired.ds$views <- log(paired.ds$views)
}


##### Create time series

unemployment.ts<-ts(paired.ds$unemployment,freq=12, start=c(year(paired.ds$date[1]), month(paired.ds$date[1])) ) 

views.ts<-ts(paired.ds$views,freq=12, start=c(year(paired.ds$date[1]),month(paired.ds$date[1])))


##### First model

model.ts <- cbind(unemployment.ts, views.ts) 

#### Seasonality 
## Test first for seasonality
s.unemployment <- unemployment.ts
s.views <- views.ts

#### Fix seasonality if nsdiffs > 0
ns.unemp <- nsdiffs(unemployment.ts)
if(ns.unemp > 0) {
  print(sprintf("Found seasonality in unemployment of %s", ns.unemp))
  s.unemployment <- diff(s.unemployment,lag=frequency(s.unemployment),differences=ns.unemp)
} 

####  Fix seasonality if nsdiffs > 0
ns.views <- nsdiffs(views.ts)
if(ns.views > 0) {
  print(sprintf("Found seasonality in viewst of %s", ns.views))
  s.views <- diff(s.views,lag=frequency(s.views),differences=ns.views)
} 



#### Integration
lag.unemployment  =ndiffs(s.unemployment, alpha = 0.05, test = c("adf"))
d.unemployment = s.unemployment

####  Integraate of ndiffs > 0

if (lag.unemployment >0){
  print(sprintf("Found integration in unemployment of %s", lag.unemployment))
  d.unemployment = diff(d.unemployment, lag=lag.unemployment)
}


####  Integraate of ndiffs > 0
lag.views = ndiffs(s.views, alpha = 0.05, test = c("adf"))
d.views = s.views

if (lag.views >0){
  print(sprintf("Found integration in views of %s", lag.views))
  d.views = diff(d.views, lag=lag.views)
}



#Model 2
#### Make it stationary

model2.ts <- cbind(d.unemployment, d.views)
max.lag <- max(lag.unemployment, lag.views) #### see which one has bigger lag, in this particular example it is lag.views = 1




#### Here we divide data in training and testing and fix the time window. Since lag.views =1, the first element in model2.ts is NA's, so we start the 
##### by the next date that is no NA, which is Feb 2008

model3.ts <- window(model2.ts, 
                    start=c(year(as.Date(as.yearmon(time(model2.ts))[1+ max.lag]) ), month(as.Date(as.yearmon(time(model2.ts))[1+ max.lag]) )),
                    end = c( tail(year(as.Date(as.yearmon(time(model2.ts))) ), 6)[1], tail(month(as.Date(as.yearmon(time(model2.ts))) ), 6)[1])
)
testdata <- window(model2.ts, 
                   start=c( tail(year(as.Date(as.yearmon(time(model2.ts))) ), 5)[1], tail(month(as.Date(as.yearmon(time(model2.ts))) ), 5)[1])
)


###### The VARselect() enables the user to determine an optimal lag length according to an information criteria or the final
###### prediction error of an empirical VAR(p) process

pos.lags <- VARselect(model3.ts, lag.max = 10)$selection
## result
##AIC(n)  HQ(n)  SC(n) FPE(n) 
##3      3      2      3 

## choose AIC
var = VAR(model3.ts, p=pos.lags[1], type="const")
p.value <- serial.test(var, lags.pt=10, type="PT.asymptotic")
roots(var) # stable model has all roots <1
# result of roots
# 0.8767457 0.8767457 0.6394563 0.6394563 0.5066303 0.5066303

# serial.test It is tested for autocorrelation in errors using a portmanteau test. The null hypothesis of no autocorrelation is rejected when the pp-value < 0.05
### Since autocorrelation is an undesirable feature of the model, we want to look for another model that does not have autocorrelation. We want
### a p value such that the null of no autocorrelation cannot be rejected because the pp-value > 0.05
if(p.value$serial$p.value > 0.05) { 
  ### Test for Granger causality 
  ### It is is a statistical concept of causality that is based on prediction. According to Granger causality, 
  ### if a signal X1 "Granger-causes" (or "G-causes") a signal X2, then past values of X1 should contain information that helps predict 
  #### X2 above and beyond the information contained in past values of X2 alone



  ### does unemployment causes views? ---> NO

  result <- grangertest(model3.ts[,2] ~ model3.ts[,1], order=pos.lags[1])
  if(result$`Pr(>F)`[2] < 0.05){

    print ("**********P-VALUE VALUE LESS THAN 0.05 WE CAN SAY THAT WE CAN REJECT NON CAUSALITY, WE MAY HAVE CAUSALITY *************")

    #### predicting next 5 months, *****  here is my doubt! How is the predict calculated? 
    ##### how to know two time series in better than one?
    p<- predict(var, n.ahead=5, ci=0.95) 
    fcst = forecast(var, h = 5)
    print( accuracy( fcst, testdata))

  }

  ### does views causes unemployment? ---> YES
  result <- grangertest(model3.ts[,1] ~ model3.ts[,2], order=pos.lags[1])
  if(result$`Pr(>F)`[2] < 0.05){

    print ("**********P-VALUE VALUE LESS THAN 0.05 WE CAN SAY THAT WE CAN REJECT NON CAUSALITY, WE MAY HAVE CAUSALITY *************")


    #### predicting next 5 months, *****  here is my doubt! How is the predict calculated? 
    ##### how to know two time series in better than one?
    p<- predict(var, n.ahead=5, ci=0.95) 
    fcst = forecast(var, h = 5)
    print( accuracy(fcst, testdata))
    plot(var)
    plot(p)
  }

}
######## enf od stackoverflow
```

Comment: These aren't really programming questions, these are questions about how to perform a proper statistical analysis. You should post such questions over at [stats.se], not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well its a bit programing as well since I don't know for instance how to compare with AR.  I would appreciate of someone could help me with the comparison plot. In any case, I will post it in cross validated as well

Comment: Im trying to post this in cross validated and they tell me that I ca  only post once every 40 minutes! argh!

Comment: Is that even a one of the 4 questions you asked above? If you need help with a plot, take away all the non-essential information. Create a [reproduicble example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data that doesn't rely on files in your dropbox we don't have access to.

Comment: You are totally right. I forgot to remove those ...how can I edit the question?

Comment: Ok , I edited my question.